# Transaction management using SQLAlchemy Core and Flask Python fails with Apache

Tags: python, apache, sqlalchemy

Have a Flask web application with API calls and transaction management using SQLAlchemy Core. While inserting/updating into  multiple tables simultaneously, the code excerpt that takes care of it:

```
import os
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
DB_URL="postgresql://tasksys:ekhycsEdorv8@localhost/mydb"
engine = create_engine(DB_URL, strategy='threadlocal')
conn = engine.connect()

trans = conn.begin()
try:
   for x in new_list:
       ins = a_table.insert().values(a_table.c.id=x)
       rs1 = conn.execute(ins)
       stmt = d_table.update().values(data).where(d_table.c.id == x)
       conn.execute(stmt)
   trans.commit()
   return jsonify({"message":"added and updated"}), 204
except Exception, e:
   print e
   trans.rollback()
```

This works when it is run in a screen with runserver.py. But when run using WSGI behind Apache works for some time and then fails and doesn't allow any user to login until Apache is reloaded again. The logs do not show any exception error message.
What can be done to resolve the same. Apache v. 2.4.10, Flask 0.11, **SQLAlchemy==1.0.8 Core only**

Comment: While the connection should close when it goes out of scope, could it still be possible that you're leaving connections open. There's no explicit close at least in your example, and if they linger, they're not released back to the pool.

Comment: @IljaEverilä I am not closing the connection  explicitly for each api call. The above is 1 api call. Is it necessary to close it in each api call ?

Comment: It is, if for some reason you keep references to it between calls, but I'm pretty sure I'm barking up the wrong tree.